# Timing differences between multiple executions of identical code

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, timing

I have a 
    `list` of pairs of numbers and I'd like to change the sign of the second element in each pair i.e. $(a,b)\rightarrow (a,-b)$.

I'm sure there are many ways to do this. Starting from an example list the ways I know are

```
list = Table[{j, j}, {j, 200}];

Table[{list[[s, 1]], -list[[s, 2]]}, {s, 1, Length[list], 1}]

Partition[Riffle[Transpose[list][[1]], -1 Transpose[list][[2]]], 2]

{#1, -#2} & @@@ list
```

They all produce the same output and I expected the final method to be the fastest as it utilises Mathematica's functional programming abilities. More generally I expected the timings for each method to be constant upon repetition, meaning if I executed the same code many times I'd get the same answer.

However when I timed them for 10 runs of 1000 executions each I get the following

```
Table[Timing[
   Do[Table[{list[[s, 1]], -list[[s, 2]]}, {s, 1, Length[list], 
      1}], {1000}]][[1]], {10}]

(*{0.344, 0.281, 0.312, 0.313, 0.265, 0.297, 0.328, 0.375, 0.297, 0.297}*)

Table[Timing[
   Do[Partition[Riffle[Transpose[list][[1]], -1 Transpose[list][[2]]],
      2], {1000}]][[1]], {10}]

(*{0.11, 0.093, 0.125, 0.11, 0.109, 0.094, 0.109, 0.094, 0.109, 0.125}*)


Table[Timing[Do[{#1, -#2} & @@@ list, {1000}]][[1]], {10}]

(*{0.219, 0.219, 0.219, 0.25, 0.218, 0.219, 0.25, 0.188, 0.234, 0.312}*)
```

and it seems I was wrong on both of my expectations. Variable timings and `@@@` came in second place. `Partition[Riffle.....` was approx twice as fast as the others.

Could someone explain the reasons for (a) the variable timing and (b) why the `Partition[Riffle.....` method is more efficient than the `@@@`method when I would have guessed it has more computational steps?

Comment: What about clearing your cache? Would that make a difference? And should you be using `AbsoluteTiming`?

Comment: *Two* orders of magnitude faster is the simple and natural `list . {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}`. For larger lists, the advantage grows to many orders of magnitude.

Comment: Note that the first method's time is linear with list length, while the other two's time doesn't seem to depend on the list's length.

Comment: Actually, @stevenh, the first method is worse than linear, whereas (at least eventually) the others are linear (it's impossible to do any better asymptotically). By the time the length is $10^5$, the timings for one iteration are 8.6, 0.003, and 0.1 seconds.  (The timing for the matrix multiplication is 0.0000004 seconds.)

Comment: @whuber I did try something as direct as that. Only thing is my attempt was `list.{1,-1}`. It didn't work so I started with the above. Looking back now the dimensions are obviously wrong but ya you're right that is more natural method to do it though. Thanks.

Comment: @drN I'll try that later, thanks. I have stuff running at the moment and I don't want to mess with it. If clearing the cache makes a difference I'll let you know. I tried with `AbsoluteTiming` (obviously without clearing the cache) and I got the same thing just with more decimal places. Thanks

Comment: @fizzics I seem to remember reading that `Timing` can do goofy things on multiprocessor machines and that using `AbsoluteTiming` gave more consistent results. Someone will either correct me or chime in with a link...

Comment: I don't have time to test these examples but in addition to the comments made above about caching, the default cut offs for autocompilation are usually 250 so with your first tests with 200 list elements no autocompilation would be taking place. I suspect this may have something to do with the timings in your second lot of examples. BTW I think `list[[All,2]]=-list[[All,2]]` would probably be the fastest way to achieve this result. ...and concise too.

Comment: @Mike That's a really good try and beautifully concise but it's not even close: for large lists it's almost an order of magnitude slower than matrix multiplication (e.g., 4.2 *vs*. 0.6 sec for an *integer* list of length $10^8$; 4.9 *vs.* 1.2 sec for a *double precision* list of the same length).

Comment: @whuber yes i agree for integer lists, however the big speed advantages seem to disappear when using lists of reals. On my system I do notice the matrix multiplication to be a ~10% faster for large lists of reals. The OP uses integers in their example list of course.

Comment: @Mike Thank you for those interesting results: your system looks better than mine for floating point computations compared to integer computations (by a factor of about three, it seems).

Comment: @whuber interestingly the advantage of matrix multiplication for integers on my system was greater (i.e. m m was much faster for integers) compared to the results in your comment. This was with 8.0.4 on mac 10.6.8 mac book pro. Thanks for this information anyway. I usually use `Part` by default so will now test more frequently against other methods.

Comment: @whuber On my system (Win7/mma7) I find that a double Transpose method is significantly faster than Dot with packed integers: with `list = RandomInteger[99, {5*^6, 2}];` then `Timing @ Do[({1, -1} list\[Transpose])\[Transpose], {10}]` takes 0.343s while 
`Timing @ Do[list.{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}, {10}]` takes 1.762s.  What do you get?

Comment: @Mr.W: 0.864 and 0.139 s, respectively: that is, 2.5 times as slow and 12 times faster.  (That's a striking disparity of 30x in relative times!)  I'm running a Xeon W3580 (3.33 GHz) on Win 7/64, *MMA* 8.0.0.0.  Perhaps *MMA* 8 has optimized its matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question are impossible to answer in detail. Let my try anyway:

**a)** No one can tell you the exact reason of the different timings on your machine. You should keep in mind that it is very possible, that one run of your computation has side-effects you are not aware of. One obvious example for such a behavior can be demonstrated when you try this on a fresh Mathematica kernel:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Prime[10^11]]
AbsoluteTiming[Prime[10^11]]
(*
 Out[1]= {5.178889, 2760727302517}
 Out[2]= {0.000018, 2760727302517}
*)
```

We just don't no all details of the MathKernel and therefore you can assume that there are things going on which lead to different execution speed.

The next thing is, that you have a computer where your Mathematica session is definitely not the only running program. Even if you close everything there are a lot of deamons and services that run in background. Can you assure that none of them is taking away a bit of your computational resources?

The solution for this is to repeat the measurement many times and if the function is very small (like yours) do it on a lot of data.

**b)** Again, the only thing you do is (as you wrote) *guessing* that `@@@` should be faster. A general rule in Mathematica is, that the available list manipulating functions are very fast. Another important point is to express the problem as natural as possible. This is a very vague sentence, but @whuber showed you exactly what I mean here. Expression your problem as matrix multiplication is indeed very fast and this is reasonable, because the `Dot` function is a very fundamental and often used operation.

**Conclusion**

Say you have a some function and you want to measure its execution time. You could run it 100 times, measure the `AbsoluteTiming` and look at the `Mean` and the `StandardDeviation` of the timings. This gives you a very stable value for the mean and it shows you, how the timing fluctuates

```
SetAttributes[measure, {HoldAll}];
measure[expr_] := #[Table[First[AbsoluteTiming[expr]], {100}]] & /@ {Mean,StandardDeviation}
```

The `HoldAll` attribute is required to evaluate your method inside the `AbsoluteTiming`.
And now you can measure the different methods. I take 10^5 values here

```
list = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100000, 2}];

measure[list.{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}]
(* {0.001563, 0.000051} *)

measure[Transpose[{1, -1}*Transpose[list]]]
(* {0.002419, 0.000181} *)

measure[Partition[Riffle[Transpose[list][[1]], -1 Transpose[list][[2]]], 2]]
(* {0.005972, 0.000133} *)

measure[{#1, -#2} & @@@ list]
(* {0.125322, 0.001092} *)
```

Comment: List manipulation functions fast? Don't forget Append and Prepend. They are excruciatingly slow.

Comment: +1. You will discover yet another explanation if you study the full distribution of times: *timing is discrete and coarse.* Use `measure[expr_, n_] := 
 SortBy[Tally[
   Table[Round[First[AbsoluteTiming[expr;]], .00001], {n}]], First]` and experiment like this: `results1 = measure[list.{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}, 100]`. Despite the rounding to five decimal places, the results will usually be in whole multiples of 0.001, give or take some (single precision!) floating point error.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Fair enough, but try to guess the experience level of the OP compared to yours. Do you really think it's a good idea to not lead him to the usage of more list manipulation functions? It is *a general* rule that they are in most cases faster than the procedural solutions we often complain about. When someone finally has dug deeper into the topic, he'll see why `Append` and `Prepend` have to be slow in the light of how arrays are implemented in Mma.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries And if (s)he asks then whether it is possible to improve the speed of `Append` you can refer him to e.g. David Wagners book on page 309.

Comment: @whuber Good point. I didn't check this. Why didn't you just edit my post and add the information? :-)

Comment: That's the Flatten[{{{list,elem},elem},elem}] trick?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes. With a different `Head` than `List` itself this works too even when elements itself are lists.

Comment: @halirutan Many thanks for your response. It's understandable and answers my questions. While trying to figure out what might be going on inside Mma I forgot about what might be going on elsewhere on my PC. But just to clarify are you encouraging me or discouraging me from using built in list functions? Elsewhere on this site it seems like the `/@` and `#&` approach is, in general, strongly recommended. I have only recently begun to learn functional programming and am enjoying the challenge of learning to think in that manner. Thanks again

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries @halirutan Is there an online copy of that book you mention? It seems its out of print and I can't actually find the trick to improve `Append`. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @fizzics No, I haven't found anything. I took me 6 month to find a reseller on amazon. Can you [join the chat?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica)

Comment: @fizzics I now remember that I have written something about the alternatives to `AppendTo`. Please check this [answer on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8455031/1078614)